# Find all $x \in \Bbb Z_{143} $ so $x^{2}\equiv1 \pmod{143}$

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, congruences, prime-factorization

$143=11\cdot13$

$\varphi(143)=120$ and $gcd(120,2)=2$

How do I continue?

Comment: Solve $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{11}$ and $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{13}$ and then apply Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: How do I solve that?

for $x^2\equiv1 \pmod{11}$, I check all $x \in \{0,1,...,10\}$ and see if it maintain the equation?

Comment: Or use that $11$ is prime, and so $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ is divisible by $11$ when...

Comment: for $x^2\equiv1 \pmod{11}$,so: $x=10$ or $x=12=1$ or $ x=(-10)$ or $ x=(-12)$
$$$$
for $x^2\equiv1 \pmod{13}$,so:$x=12$ or $x=14=1$ or $x=(-14)$ or $x=(-12)$
$$$$
How do I apply Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: By CRT you obtain $4$ systems, so $4$ solutions ! Obviously it's true by the field's properties

Comment: @Asaf $-12\equiv 14\pmod {13}$ and $-14\equiv 12\pmod{13}$ and $-10\equiv 12\pmod{11}$ and $-12\equiv 10\pmod{11}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go :

First notice that $143=11\times 13$.

The method is that we will solve the equation $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$ and $x^2\equiv 1 \pmod{13}$ and after we'll apply the CRT.

This equivalent to solve :

$(x-1)(x+1)\equiv 0 \pmod{11}$ and $(x-1)(x+1)\equiv 0 \pmod{13}$. We know that $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/13\mathbb{Z}$ are fields. But easier, $11$ and $13$ are prime numbers so you can apply Euclid's lemma. For each equation you have $11\mid (x-1)$ or $(x+1)$ and $13 \mid (x-1)$ or $(x+1)$.

It gives you four possibilities (or four systems) :

$\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
           x_1 &\equiv 1 \pmod{11} \\
           x_1 &\equiv 1 \pmod{13} \\
           \end{array}
            \right.$
    $\Rightarrow \ x_1\equiv 13y_1+11z_1 \pmod{143}$.

$\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
       x_2 &\equiv -1 \pmod{11} \\
       x_2 &\equiv 1 \pmod{13} \\
       \end{array}
        \right.$
    $\Rightarrow \ x_2\equiv -13y_2+11z_2 \pmod{143}$.

$\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
       x_3 &\equiv 1 \pmod{11} \\
       x_3 &\equiv -1 \pmod{13} \\
       \end{array}
        \right.$
    $\Rightarrow \ x_3\equiv 13y_3-11z_3 \pmod{143}$.

$\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
       x_4 &\equiv -1 \pmod{11} \\
       x_4 &\equiv -1 \pmod{13} \\
       \end{array}
        \right.$
    $\Rightarrow \ x_4\equiv -13y_4-11z_4 \pmod{143}$.

Now by the conditions of the CRT we must have :

$13y_1\equiv 1 \pmod{11}\Rightarrow y_1\equiv 6 \pmod{11}$ and $11z_1 \equiv 1 \pmod{13} \Rightarrow z_1 \equiv 6 \pmod{13}\Rightarrow x_1\equiv 1\pmod{143}$.

$13y_2\equiv 1 \pmod{11}\Rightarrow y_2\equiv 6 \pmod{11}$ and $11z_2 \equiv 1 \pmod{13} \Rightarrow z_2 \equiv 6 \pmod{13}\Rightarrow x_2\equiv -12=131\pmod{143}$.

$13y_3\equiv 1 \pmod{11}\Rightarrow y_3\equiv 6 \pmod{11}$ and $11z_3 \equiv 1 \pmod{13} \Rightarrow z_3 \equiv 6 \pmod{13}\Rightarrow x_3\equiv 12\pmod{143}$.

$13y_4\equiv 1 \pmod{11}\Rightarrow y_4\equiv 6 \pmod{11}$ and $11z_4 \equiv 1 \pmod{13} \Rightarrow z_4 \equiv 6 \pmod{13}\Rightarrow x_4\equiv -1=142\pmod{143}$.

Comment: Thanks.I solved it same as you.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 143$

$x^2 -1 \equiv 0 \mod 11*13$

$11*13|(x+1)(x-1)$

So there are four cases:  where either $11|x \pm 1$; $13|x \pm 1$.

Case 1:  $11*13|x-1< 142$.  $x=1$

Case 2: $11*13|x+1.$  $x= 142$

Case 3: $11|x-1; 13|x+1$

$x = 11m + 1; x = 13j -1$ so $13j-11m = 2$ and $13(j + 11i) - 11(m + 13i) = 2$.  So $(j,m) = (1,1);x = 12$ or $(1+11i,1+13i); x=12+ 143i$.

Case 4: $13|x-1$. $11|x+1$

$x=13m +1 = 11j - 1; 13(m+11i)- 11(j+13i) =-2;$ so $(j,m) =(-1,-1);x=-12 + 143i$ or $x = 131$.

So $x = 1,12,131,142$

Which is basically the chinese remainder theorem without knowing the chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: * is for $\times$ (multiplication) ? In your 4th line it seems that you apply euclid lemma ?

Comment: Euclid's lemma? well.... obviously.  I mean does it really not to be stated that if MN=k*p*q and p,q are prime that the primes divide one or another of the factors M, N?

Comment: Ok no problem but the fact is that it's not true for $k$ (just as a remark). For $11,13$ it works.

Comment: The prime factors of k must also divide one or the other.  So what?  We don't give a toss about k, and showing that x +- 1 have divisors that are also divisors of k which could be anything including 1 is pointless.

Comment: Indeed it works for the prime factors of $k$ not for $k$

Comment: Yeah... but it is so totally irrelevant (and to be honest trivial), I see no reason to bring it up.  We are trying to find solutions to x and 11 or 13 dividing x +- 1 is relevent.  That the prime or unit factors of an unknown k which could be anything will divide x +- 1 means ... x +-1 are integers.  k is not in the least bit significant. I *only* wrote it in the possibility that the OP wouldn't be comfortable with $(x+1)(x-1)\equiv 0 \mod 11*13 \implies 11,13|x\pm 1$ which becomes obvious when written as $(x+1)(x-1) = k*11*13$. the k is **UTTERLY UNIMPORTANT**.  No one gives a ---- about $k$.

Comment: It's just to avoid confusion. Someone could have said "$k$ can divide one of the factor".

Comment: They could say "animals can eat food". One more time. k IS IRRELEVANT.  Look.  Suppose I told you that 4|108  that means 108 = 4 x something. So, that means... hold on to you hats... that something divides 108... Geek, gosh oh, mickle dilly pickle!!!! can you *BELIEVE* that  SOMETHING DIVIDES 108!!!!!!  so so yes, k is is something and.... surprise! x-1 or x +1 is divisible by something.  one more time with exclamation points:  !! k IS NOT IMPORTANT; k IS IRRELEVANT!!! k could be anything.  k could by 1. so SOMETHING divides x +1 and something else divides x-1. That is TRIVIAL AND OBVIOUS!!!!

Comment: $k$ divides the product but is not necessary coprime with one of the term of the product so we cannot affirm that $k$ divides one of the term of the product.

Comment: What do you not understand about "k is irrelevent"? k could be one.  k could be *anything*.  $k|(x+1)(x-1) \iff (x+1)(x-1) $ is an integer.  That is the *only* relevance that k has.  11x13xk =(x+1)(x-1) means i) 11x13|(x+1)(x-1) and ii) 11x3 $\le $ (x+1)(x-1).  That is ALL k means.  There is NOTHING that k can tell us directly. k DOESN'T MATTER.

Comment: There!!  I've editted the answer.  k is dead!.  k is rotting in hell where it belongs.  k never existed.  Down with k and long live the 0 modulo residue!  k is worm food.

Comment: Also, you do realize that in all cases it turned out that k =1.  All four cases (x+1)(x-1)= 11x13.  There *was* no k (other than 1, the multiplication identity.)

Comment: Indeed the only thing we can say about $k$ is that it divides the product and dats all. It doesn't have an impact on the final answer for sure . But someone could have made a mistake saying that $k$ divides one of the term of the product. It's just for avoiding confusion on "numbers"...

Comment: What on earth is your point?  a = kb with no other information means saying k|a is not a mistake but is trivially and pointlessly true.  Who cares if someone says k|a? If we give a damn about what k is we solve it by solving x first and figuring k = x^2 -1/143.k is simply of no relevence but it's also nothing of significance that anyone would be confused by and use in solving this problem.  So why on earth do you keep harping on it?  Anyway k IS DEAD.  It is no longer mentioned in my post *ANYWHERE*.

Comment: It's exactly what I said in the previous comment... And I said that the problem is solved.